# MySQL query returns multiples of each result

Tags: mysql

I have the queries below that return each a table to hold the information queried.

Each of these queries aren't quite working. The first two return all the results that I am looking for, but multiples of each entry (row):

```
    "SELECT`products`.*, `orderdetails`.*, `orders`.*
     FROM `orders`
     INNER JOIN `orderdetails` ON `orderdetails`.`orderNumber` =     `orders`.`orderNumber`
     INNER JOIN `products` ON `orderdetails`.`productCode` = `products`.`productCode`
     WHERE orders.status = 'Cancelled'";


    "SELECT `products`.*, `orderdetails`.*, `orders`.*
     FROM `orders`
     LEFT JOIN `orderdetails` ON `orderdetails`.`orderNumber` = `orders`.`orderNumber`
     LEFT JOIN `products` ON `orderdetails`.`productCode` = `products`.`productCode`
     WHERE orders.status = 'In Process'";
```

The last one, I am just not sure whats wrong with it. No information gets displayed at all. The code is broken. I do want to basically do the same thing as the queries above, but show only the first 20 rows.

```
    "SELECT `products`.*, `orderdetails`.*, `orders`.*
     FROM `orders`
     LEFT JOIN `orderdetails` ON `orderdetails`.`orderNumber` = `orders`.`orderNumber`
     LEFT JOIN `products` ON `orderdetails`.`productCode` = `products`.`productCode` 
     GROUP BY orderNumber ORDER BY max(orderDate) DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Why are my first two tables display multiples of each entry? And what error do I have in my last query?

Here's a screenshot of the wrong output:

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvOlb.png)

Here's the ER Diagram of the tables. I am looking to display: ProductCode, ProductLine, ProductName, Comments, OrderNumber, OrderDate, Status.

[ER_Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfpPe.png)

As for my understanding, I have to join the tables: OrderDetails, Products, and Orders.

Comment: `GROUP BY orderNumber` -> `GROUP BY orders.orderNumber`
And the same with `max(orderDate)`

Comment: that worked, thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the third query won't work because you are using Group by without any aggregate functions. Most likely you need this

```
SELECT `products`.*, `orderdetails`.*, `orders`.*, max(orderDate)
     FROM `orders`
     LEFT JOIN `orderdetails` ON `orderdetails`.`orderNumber` = `orders`.`orderNumber`
     LEFT JOIN `products` ON `orderdetails`.`productCode` = `products`.`productCode` 
     GROUP BY orderNumber ORDER BY max(orderDate) DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: Also you can use Distinct in the first query to get rid of duplicate rows.

Comment: I tried that, but maybe I entered it incorrectly, because it didn't work. I basically had:    "SELECT DISTINCT `products`.*, `orderdetails`.*, `orders`.*

Comment: Any other suggestions? I might just be doing this wrong.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT seems to be right to me, what do you mean by it is not working? (i.e. no results or still have duplicate) and what about the "Group by" query.

Comment: It still contains all the duplicates, nothing changed when I added distinct. For example, when you look at my sample table output in my main question, the customer with the number "10167" shows up way too many times, where it should only display one row of this instance

Comment: Try the following syntax
'SELECT *
FROM orders, orderdetails, products
WHERE orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber AND orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode AND orders.status ='Cancelled';'

Comment: Still doesn't work, I am clueless what could be wrong. Thank you for helping.